# Install Docker Ubuntu 16.04 -- Not finding packages

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

My morning so far has been banging my head against trying to get the docker installation to work, so far I have had no luck.

The guide I have been following: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Here is the steps of what happens.

First:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

[image]

Which is good! The next step is a `sudo apt-get update` which returns something less good. A lot of documentation I have read does not seem to help me solve this, so I plug on to see if something will correct this later.
[image]

Third step is

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

No issues here.

Fourth step is the docker fingerprint key

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Which just outputs OK

Fifth step I do is the `sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88` which outputs the key as it is shown in the docker installation documentation.

Sixth step is the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
```

No output is shown just brings me to a new command line.

Seventh step is `sudo apt-get update` which shows the same output as in step 2.

Eigth step is the actual install. `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`
 Which outputs: 
[image]

I am not sure of what files to edit. But every line is spelled correctly and it still throws issues my way and I am at a loss. If anyone has any tips thatd be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure which steps error, I suggest you to ease the process of the docker install using official convenience script, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script):

Main steps as next:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple way to install, as this is a common problem:

Download the most recent docker-ce, docker cli and container.d file from here:

https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/

Then just run `dpkg -i <containerd package name> <docker-ce package name> <docker cli package name>`

That's it, Docker away

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is blocked through the DNS, You can try by changing DNS address to  8.8.8.8.
you can change DNS address through /etc/resolve.conf temporarily
or if you need permanent you can change here **/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base**